# nested list model binding and HTML helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to create an editor in ASP.NET MVC 2 for a list of check boxes.  The collection of these checkboxes is based off of a database table.  I'm having trouble getting the names to come out correctly so that the values post...

ViewModels:

```
public class EAF
{
    // other properties
    public IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> _products { get; set; }
}

public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int ProductPK { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Main View:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(m => m._products, "ProductListTemplate") %>
```

Editor Template (list):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IList<EmployeeAccessForm.Models.ProductViewModel>>" %>

<fieldset>
<legend>REQUEST FOR:  (select item(s) to display access form)</legend>
<table>
    <tr>
<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) { %>
    <td>
    <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model[i], "ProductCheckBox") %>
    </td>
    <% if (i+1 % 5 == 0) { %>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
    </tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
```

Editor Template (item):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<EmployeeAccessForm.Models.ProductViewModel>" %>

<%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductPK)%>
<%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsSelected)%>
<%: Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.ProductName)%>
```

I get a table of checkboxes as expected, but when I view the source, the inputs all have a name like `_products.[0].ProductPK` where I need it to be `_products[0].ProductPK` (without the first dot).  Is there a way using the helpers to get the names to come out like the latter?  I can do it by writing out the HTML explicitly but wondered if I could still use the helpers and get the right naming.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is coming from using an editor template for the list. Even though you didn't post it, I'm assuming in your main view you have something like:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(m => m._products, "ProductListTemplate") %>
```

This results in a prefix being added of `_products`. Then in your list template, the field names there are being bound in the form of `[0].ProductPK`. So the result is `_products.[0].ProductPK`.

Instead in your main view you should be doing:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>REQUEST FOR:  (select item(s) to display access form)</legend>
<table>
    <tr>
<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) { %>
    <td>
    <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model._products[i], "ProductCheckBox") %>
    </td>
    <% if (i+1 % 5 == 0) { %>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
    </tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
```

In other words, remove that middle layer that's screwing up the field names. Since the expression being passed here `model._products[i]`, your field names will be prefixed with `_products[0]`.

If your goal with the list template was simply to reuse this portion of the view, you can still do that but the model you pass into should be your `EAF` class, and then you'd use `Html.Partial` instead of `Html.EditorFor`:

```
<%: Html.Partial("ProductListTemplate") %>
```

**ProductListTemplate.cshtml**

```
@model Namespace.To.EAF

...

<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model._products[i], "ProductCheckBox") %>
```

Comment: For clarity I added the piece about what the main view looked like.  And your suggestion worked perfectly with the partial view plus EAF model in lieu of the editor template!  Thanks for your help!